# Check for unique values in a dictionary and return a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've been struggling with this exercise for a couple of days now, each approximation I find, have a new problem, the idea is to find those unique values on a dictionary, and return a list with the keys

For example:
if `aDictionary  = {1: 1, 3: 2, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 4, 10: 0}` then your the function should return `[1, 3, 8]`, as the values 1,2 and 4 only appear once.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def existsOnce(aDict):

counting = {}
tempList = []

for k in aDict.keys():
    print k,
    print aDict[k]


print 'values are:'
for v in aDict.values():
    print v,
    counting[v] = counting.get(v,0)+1
    print counting[v]
    tempNumbers = counting[v]
    tempList.append(tempNumbers)
print tempList
```

If I go this way, I can point and delete those that are bigger than one, but the problem persists, I will have one zero, and I don't want it as was not unique in the original list.

```
def existsOnce2(aDict):

# import Counter module in the top with `from collections import Counter`

c = Counter()

for letter in 'here is a sample of english text':
    c[letter] += 1
    if c[letter] == 1:
        print c[letter],':',letter
```

I tried to go this way with integers and check which ones appear from first time, but cannot translate it to dictionary or keep going from here. Also I'm not sure if importing modules are allowed in the answer and surely have to be a way to do it without external modules.

```
def existsOnce3(aDict):

    vals = {}
    for i in aDict.values():
        for j in set(str(i)):
            vals[j] = 1+ vals.get(j,0)
    print vals

    '''till here I get a counter of how many times a value appears in the original dictionary, now I should delete those bigger than 1'''
    temp_vals = vals.copy()
    for x in vals:
        if vals[x] > 1:
            print 'delete this: ', 'key:',x,'value:', vals[x]
            temp_vals.pop(x)
        else:
            pass
    print 'temporary dictionary values:', temp_vals
    '''till here I reduced down the values that appear once, 1, 2 and 4, now I would need the go back and check the original dictionary and return the keys
        Original dictionary: {1: 1, 3: 2, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 4, 10: 0}
        temp_vals {'1': 1, '2': 1, '4': 1}
        keys on temp_vals (1,2,4) are the values associated to the keys I got to retrieve from original dictionary (1,3,8)
    '''
    print '---'

    temp_list = []
    for eachTempVal in temp_vals:
        temp_list.append(eachTempVal)
    print 'temporary list values:', temp_list
    ''' till here I got a temporary list with the values I need to search in aDict'''
    print '---'
    for eachListVal in temp_list:
        print 'eachListVal:', eachListVal
        for k,v in aDict.iteritems():
            print 'key:',k,'value:',v
```

From here I cannot take the values for whatever reason and compare them, I've tried to extract the values with statements like:

```
if v == eachListVal:
    do something
```

But I'm doing something wrong and cannot access to the values.

Comment: If the values are immutable create a second dictionary keyed by the values in the first where the values in the second dictionary are counts of the number of times that they appear in the first dictionary. From there a single line of code returns the list you want. It should all fit in at most 6 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use your `vals` dict and keep keys from `aDict` with values that have a `count == 1` in vals then calling sorted to get a sorted output list:

```
def existsOnce3(aDict):  
    vals = {}
    # create dict to sum all value counts
    for i in aDict.values():
        vals.setdefault(i,0)
        vals[i] += 1   
    # use each v/val from aDict as the key to vals
    # keeping each k/key from aDict if the count is 1
    return sorted(k for k, v in aDict.items() if vals[v] == 1)
```

Using a collections.Counter dict to do the counting just call Counter on your values then apply the same logic, just keep each k that has a v count == 1 from the Counter dict:

```
from collections import Counter
cn = Counter(aDict.values())
print(sorted(k for k,v in aDict.items() if cn[v] == 1))
```

Comment: Great! I still don't fully understandthis line:  `return sorted(k for k, v in aDict.items() if vals[v] == 1)`. Any useful link to documentation?

Comment: @gma992, it just sorts the keys from lowest to highest to guarantee you get the order required, dicts are unordered so there is no guarantee you would get `[1,3,8]` without calling sorted. https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting The `if vals[v] == 1` makes sure we only keep the keys whose values were not repeated,  if the value returned for `v` in your vals dict was not `1` then we know it is not a unique value

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
from collections import Counter

my_dict  = {1: 1, 3: 2, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 4, 10: 0}

val_counter = Counter(my_dict.itervalues())
my_list = [k for k, v in my_dict.iteritems() if val_counter[v] == 1]

print my_list
```

Result:

```
[1, 3, 8]
```

Comment: `[k for k, v in my_dict.items() if val_counter[v] == 1]`, no need to create `uniques` first

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
>>> aDictionary  = {1: 1, 3: 2, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 4, 10: 0}
>>> unique_values = [k for k,v in aDictionary.items() if list(aDictionary.values()).count(v)==1]
>>> unique_values
[1, 3, 8]
```

Comment: This is quadratic as Opposed to `O(n)` using the OP's dict approach